# SSIS and xml - xml source task output doesn't show all the nodes/columns

Tags: ssis

I have a complicated xml doc that i'm trying to load to sql db through SSIS. XML source output doesn't show all the columns/nodes. It's like root nodes are ignored.

I have tried following posts that are talking about xml task and xlst without winning.

I can only see columns under Wagons tag. Sender,Receiver, ManagerType, TrainNumber, TrainType,Origin,Destination,etc don't appear as columns output.

I'm trying to upload a sample

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<VehicleList>
  <Sender>ZAJHBTFR</Sender>
  <Receiver>EXXARO - Tintas Drift</Receiver>
  <MessageType>CoalVehicleListOut</MessageType>
  
  <WAGONS>
    <SNo>01</SNo>
    <WagonNumber>61</WagonNumber>
    <WagonType>CR4</WagonType>
    <Owner>SAV</Owner>
    <TareMass>0019650</TareMass>
    <TagReaderDateTime>20140206</TagReaderDateTime>
  </WAGONS>
  <WAGONS>
    <SNo>02</SNo>
    <WagonNumber>601</WagonNumber>lrkg
    <WagonType>CGR2</WagonType>
    <Owner>SAV</Owner>
    <TareMass>02</TareMass>
    <TagReaderDateTime>2014</TagReaderDateTime>
  </WAGONS>
 </VehicleList>

Comment: Are you aware that the XML source can produce multiple outputs, one for each "level" in the input doc.  Perhaps the missing columns are coming out in a different output?